# Absolute positioning breaks the structure completely

Tags: html, css, position

Here's the basic **HTML** code:

```
<div class="soc-cont">
    <div class="soc-item-cont" style="background: blue;">
        <div class="soc-item">
            <img src="img/facebook.png" style="width: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the **CSS**:

```
.soc-cont {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}

.soc-item-cont {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.soc-item-cont:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

.soc-item {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is add `position: absolute` and `left: 0` to to the `img` in order to take it out of the usual document flow to be able to overlap it with another picture later on. But instead of working as it should, I get this:
[image]

Instead of this:
[image]

*Note: I have color-coded it a little to be more easily understood.*
***It also should be noted that there are, in fact, four `.soc-item`s. However, since they are, right now, nothing more than copies to fill up the space, I didn't deem it necessary to post it here, as it would probably confuse you even more.***

However, all it takes is changing `position` to `absolute` to instantly break the look.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: you don't need to change to absolute position to do that , if I am understanding you correctly.  if by "to take it out of the usual document flow" you just mean hide , then just set display to none when you want it hidden or z-index to -1

Comment: Use https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ for centering.

Comment: @ScottSelby Of course, that would work if just "taking it out of the usual document flow" was my sole objective. But you see, I said that I'm doing this because I plan to overlap this image with another one, and then exchange opacities with each other on hover. But I could've just done this by simply changing `src` using JavaScript. However, since I want to do it with a transition, the only possible way is crossfading. Simply using `display: none` isn't going to cut it.

Comment: is the width of the images always known?  if so then to center with absolute position you just do left: 50% and margin-left: -10px   ,  if the width is 20px , the left margin is minus half the width

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem is that, by changing it to position:absolute, you are taking it out of the normal flow but that causes your div(s) to collapse cause they now have no content (essentially). Once they do, you have to deal with the image being on the baseline and having white space, just like text. So it's the same as if you inserted or removed that content. Your layout "adjusts" to the content.

Comment: I would say if the question was "why is this happening" then this would be a correct answer , but the question was how to fix this

Comment: @ScottSelby That answer would make the question too broad. There are too many possible answers and we don't know his design goal.

Comment: exactly, that is why I just left a comment .  The question should be fixed or closed